# Wordpress AJAX - how to return true or false in the callback function

Tags: ajax

So I've set up AJAX with Wordpress properly, having followed some good tutorials, and it's working great. One thing I can't quite work out is how to properly return either TRUE or FALSE from within the callback function.

My php function is as follows:

```
function my_callback() {
    if(something()) {
        echo 'false';
    } else {
        echo 'true';
    }
    exit;
}
```

In the JS do I simply do `if(response == 'true') { // do something }` or is there a better way?
This might seem a little trivial but this is the first time I'm really using AJAX!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

this would work to:

```
function my_callback() {
    if(something()) {
        echo 1;
    }
    exit; //no text sent or even exit('0'); will work
}
```

and in js:

```
var response = do_ajax();
if(response){
    //do stuff
}
```